# Creating a mask out of a custom shape drawn with sprites using action script 3

Tags: flash, actionscript-3

I'm trying to create a mask out of a custom shape, is there any way to convert the shape object to a mask object? The shape is drawn dynamically in code using as3. I can't seem to find any links to do something like this.

Here's the code to create the application:

```
var numPoints:Number = 0;       //  Number of points placed. 
                                //  No dragging will work until all three points are placed.

//  Set max & min stage coordinates that the points can be dragged, and make the point diameters settable.
var xMax:Number = 455;
var xMin:Number = 5;
var yMax:Number = 305;
var yMin:Number = 5;
var circleWidth:Number = 10;

//  Boolean variables to indicate that dragging is happening so that the appropriate point follows the mouse
//  on the MOUSE_MOVE event.
var isDragging1:Boolean = false;
var isDragging2:Boolean = false;
var isDragging3:Boolean = false;
var isDragging4:Boolean = false;
var isDragging5:Boolean = false;
var isDragging6:Boolean = false;
var isDragging7:Boolean = false;
var isDragging8:Boolean = false;

//  The drawBoard is a rectangle on which the triangle will be drawn.  Colors are settable here. To change size,
//  change the variables xMin, xMax, yMin, yMax above.
var drawBoard:Sprite = new Sprite();
drawBoard.graphics.lineStyle(1, 0x000000);
drawBoard.graphics.beginFill(0xEFEF77);
drawBoard.graphics.drawRect(0, 0, xMax - xMin, yMax - yMin);
drawBoard.graphics.endFill();
drawBoard.x = xMin;
drawBoard.y = yMin;

//  Add a default drop shadow filter to the drawBoard
drawBoard.filters = [ new DropShadowFilter() ];

//  This rectangle will listen for mouse clicks in order to construct the three vertices of the triangle.
drawBoard.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, placePoint);

//  Put on the stage the board on which the triangle will be drawn.
stage.addChild(drawBoard);

//  The filled triangle consists of three lines drawn between the points. It is updated on MOUSE_MOVE once 
//  dragging starts.
var lines:Shape = new Shape();
drawBoard.addChild(lines);


//  The stage will listen for events involving dragging so that the dragging will continue to work even after
//  the mouse has rolled off of the drawBoard region.
stage.addEventListener(MouseEvent.MOUSE_MOVE, mouseUpdate);
stage.addEventListener(MouseEvent.MOUSE_UP, stopDragging);

//  We add three points to the stage but we do not add the graphics yet.  We do specify listeners
//  at this time so when they are all placed, we will be able to drag them.

var point1:Sprite = new Sprite();
point1.addEventListener(MouseEvent.MOUSE_DOWN, startDragging1);
drawBoard.addChild(point1);

var point2:Sprite = new Sprite();
point2.addEventListener(MouseEvent.MOUSE_DOWN, startDragging2);
drawBoard.addChild(point2);

var point3:Sprite = new Sprite();
point3.addEventListener(MouseEvent.MOUSE_DOWN, startDragging3);
drawBoard.addChild(point3);

var point4:Sprite = new Sprite();
point4.addEventListener(MouseEvent.MOUSE_DOWN, startDragging4);
drawBoard.addChild(point4);

var point5:Sprite = new Sprite();
point5.addEventListener(MouseEvent.MOUSE_DOWN, startDragging5);
drawBoard.addChild(point5);

var point6:Sprite = new Sprite();
point6.addEventListener(MouseEvent.MOUSE_DOWN, startDragging6);
drawBoard.addChild(point6);

var point7:Sprite = new Sprite();
point7.addEventListener(MouseEvent.MOUSE_DOWN, startDragging7);
drawBoard.addChild(point7);

var point8:Sprite = new Sprite();
point8.addEventListener(MouseEvent.MOUSE_DOWN, startDragging8);
drawBoard.addChild(point8);

//  The reset button will stop all dragging, remove all children of drawBoard, and set numPoints back to 0.

btnReset.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, reset);

function reset(evt:MouseEvent):void {
    var i:Number;
    var n:Number = drawBoard.numChildren;

    isDragging1 = false;
    isDragging2 = false;
    isDragging3 = false;
    isDragging4 = false;
    isDragging5 = false;
    isDragging6 = false;
    isDragging7 = false;
    isDragging8 = false;

    point1.graphics.clear();
    point2.graphics.clear();
    point3.graphics.clear();
    point4.graphics.clear();
    point5.graphics.clear();
    point6.graphics.clear();
    point7.graphics.clear();
    point8.graphics.clear();
    lines.graphics.clear();

    numPoints = 0;
}

//  The next function is executed when the mouse is moved.  Note that if all points are not placed and nothing
//  is being dragged, this function does nothing.
function mouseUpdate(evt:MouseEvent):void {
    if (numPoints == 8) {                       
        if (isDragging1) {
            point1.x = goodX(evt.stageX);       //  Set x- & y-coordinates.  See below for definition of 
            point1.y = goodY(evt.stageY);       //      functions goodX & goodY
            lines.graphics.clear();             //  Remove lines shape and redraw it 
            drawLines();                        //      with updated coordinates.
        }
        if (isDragging2) {
            point2.x = goodX(evt.stageX);
            point2.y = goodY(evt.stageY);
            lines.graphics.clear();
            drawLines();
        }
        if (isDragging3) {
            point3.x = goodX(evt.stageX);
            point3.y = goodY(evt.stageY);
            lines.graphics.clear();
            drawLines();
        }
        if (isDragging4) {
            point4.x = goodX(evt.stageX);
            point4.y = goodY(evt.stageY);
            lines.graphics.clear();
            drawLines();
        }
        if (isDragging5) {
            point5.x = goodX(evt.stageX);       
            point5.y = goodY(evt.stageY);       
            lines.graphics.clear();             
            drawLines();                        
        }
        if (isDragging6) {
            point6.x = goodX(evt.stageX);
            point6.y = goodY(evt.stageY);
            lines.graphics.clear();
            drawLines();
        }
        if (isDragging7) {
            point7.x = goodX(evt.stageX);
            point7.y = goodY(evt.stageY);
            lines.graphics.clear();
            drawLines();
        }
        if (isDragging8) {
            point8.x = goodX(evt.stageX);
            point8.y = goodY(evt.stageY);
            lines.graphics.clear();
            drawLines();
        }
        evt.updateAfterEvent();
    }
}


/*  This function chooses the appropriate x-coordinate for a dragged point.  
    If thisX is in the draggable region, then we return it.  Otherwise, we return the max or min x value, 
    depending on which side of the draggable region thisX is on.
*/

function goodX(thisX:Number):Number {
    if (thisX < xMin) {
        return (xMin);
    }
    if (thisX > (xMax - circleWidth)) {
        return (xMax - circleWidth);
    }
    return (thisX);
}


//  This function chooses the appropriate y-coordinate for a dragged point in a manner similar to the previous function. 

function goodY(thisY:Number):Number {
    if (thisY < yMin) {
        return (yMin);
    }
    if (thisY > (yMax - circleWidth)) {
        return (yMax - circleWidth);
    }
    return thisY;
}

// This function manages the placement of points until all three points are placed. 
function placePoint(evt:MouseEvent):void {
    if (numPoints == 0) {
        point1.graphics.beginFill(0x7777FF);
        point1.graphics.drawCircle(0, 0, circleWidth/2);
        point1.graphics.endFill();
        point1.filters = [ new DropShadowFilter() ];
        point1.x = drawBoard.mouseX;
        point1.y = drawBoard.mouseY;
        numPoints = 1;
    }
    else if(numPoints == 1) {
        point2.graphics.beginFill(0x7777FF);
        point2.graphics.drawCircle(0, 0, circleWidth/2);
        point2.graphics.endFill();
        point2.filters = [ new DropShadowFilter() ];
        point2.x = drawBoard.mouseX;
        point2.y = drawBoard.mouseY;
        numPoints = 2;
    }
    else if (numPoints == 2) {
        point3.graphics.beginFill(0x7777FF);
        point3.graphics.drawCircle(0, 0, circleWidth/2);
        point3.graphics.endFill();
        point3.filters = [ new DropShadowFilter() ];
        point3.x = drawBoard.mouseX;
        point3.y = drawBoard.mouseY;
        numPoints = 3;
        lines.graphics.clear();
    }
    else if (numPoints == 3) {
        point4.graphics.beginFill(0x7777FF);
        point4.graphics.drawCircle(0, 0, circleWidth/2);
        point4.graphics.endFill();
        point4.filters = [ new DropShadowFilter() ];
        point4.x = drawBoard.mouseX;
        point4.y = drawBoard.mouseY;
        numPoints = 4;
        lines.graphics.clear();
    }
    else if (numPoints == 4) {
        point5.graphics.beginFill(0x7777FF);
        point5.graphics.drawCircle(0, 0, circleWidth/2);
        point5.graphics.endFill();
        point5.filters = [ new DropShadowFilter() ];
        point5.x = drawBoard.mouseX;
        point5.y = drawBoard.mouseY;
        numPoints = 5;
        lines.graphics.clear();
    }
    else if (numPoints == 5) {
        point6.graphics.beginFill(0x7777FF);
        point6.graphics.drawCircle(0, 0, circleWidth/2);
        point6.graphics.endFill();
        point6.filters = [ new DropShadowFilter() ];
        point6.x = drawBoard.mouseX;
        point6.y = drawBoard.mouseY;
        numPoints = 6;
        lines.graphics.clear();
    }
    else if (numPoints == 6) {
        point7.graphics.beginFill(0x7777FF);
        point7.graphics.drawCircle(0, 0, circleWidth/2);
        point7.graphics.endFill();
        point7.filters = [ new DropShadowFilter() ];
        point7.x = drawBoard.mouseX;
        point7.y = drawBoard.mouseY;
        numPoints = 7;
        lines.graphics.clear();
    }
    else if (numPoints == 7) {
        point8.graphics.beginFill(0x7777FF);
        point8.graphics.drawCircle(0, 0, circleWidth/2);
        point8.graphics.endFill();
        point8.filters = [ new DropShadowFilter() ];
        point8.x = drawBoard.mouseX;
        point8.y = drawBoard.mouseY;
        numPoints = 8;
        lines.graphics.clear();
        drawLines();
    }
}

//  Draws the three lines between the points with appropriate fill and adds a drop shadow.
function drawLines():void {
    lines.graphics.lineStyle(1, 0xFF0000);
    lines.graphics.beginFill(0xFF7777);
    lines.graphics.moveTo(point1.x, point1.y);
    lines.graphics.curveTo(point1.x + 50, point1.y + 50, point2.x, point2.y);
    lines.graphics.curveTo(point2.x + 50, point2.y + 50, point3.x, point3.y);
    lines.graphics.curveTo(point3.x + 50, point3.y + 50, point4.x, point4.y);
    lines.graphics.curveTo(point4.x + 50, point4.y + 50, point5.x, point5.y);
    lines.graphics.curveTo(point5.x + 50, point5.y + 50, point6.x, point6.y);
    lines.graphics.curveTo(point6.x + 50, point6.y + 50, point7.x, point7.y);
    lines.graphics.curveTo(point7.x + 50, point7.y + 50, point8.x, point8.y);
    lines.graphics.curveTo(point8.x + 50, point8.y + 50, point1.x, point1.y);
    /*lines.graphics.lineTo(point2.x, point2.y);
    lines.graphics.lineTo(point3.x, point3.y);
    lines.graphics.lineTo(point4.x, point4.y);
    lines.graphics.lineTo(point5.x, point5.y);
    lines.graphics.lineTo(point6.x, point6.y);
    lines.graphics.lineTo(point7.x, point7.y);
    lines.graphics.lineTo(point8.x, point8.y);
    lines.graphics.lineTo(point1.x, point1.y);*/
    lines.graphics.endFill();
    lines.filters = [ new DropShadowFilter() ];
}

//  The next functions "turn on" dragging for the point that is clicked, as long as all three points have
//  been placed.
function startDragging1(evt:MouseEvent):void {
    if (numPoints == 8) {
        isDragging1 = true;
    }
}

function startDragging2(evt:MouseEvent):void {
    if (numPoints == 8) {
        isDragging2 = true;
    }
}

function startDragging3(evt:MouseEvent):void {
    if (numPoints == 8) {
        isDragging3 = true;
    }
}

function startDragging4(evt:MouseEvent):void {
    if (numPoints == 8) {
        isDragging4 = true;
    }
}
function startDragging5(evt:MouseEvent):void {
    if (numPoints == 8) {
        isDragging5 = true;
    }
}

function startDragging6(evt:MouseEvent):void {
    if (numPoints == 8) {
        isDragging6 = true;
    }
}

function startDragging7(evt:MouseEvent):void {
    if (numPoints == 8) {
        isDragging7 = true;
    }
}

function startDragging8(evt:MouseEvent):void {
    if (numPoints == 8) {
        isDragging8 = true;
    }
}

//  Turns off dragging. This function is called when the mouse button is released anywhere on the stage.
function stopDragging(evt:MouseEvent):void {
    if (numPoints == 8) {
        isDragging1 = false;
        isDragging2 = false;
        isDragging3 = false;
        isDragging4 = false;
        isDragging5 = false;
        isDragging6 = false;
        isDragging7 = false;
        isDragging8 = false;
    }
}
```

Comment: That code could be **WAY** simpler. Like wow. Want me to refine it..?

Comment: If you know a way how? yes please.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Add the Shape to the display list with `addChild(maskShape)` and set it as a mask for your clip `targetClip.mask = maskShape` also you may have to set `.cacheAsBitmap = true` for booth clips (regarding of its contents). `targetClip` and `maskShape` should have the same parent.

PS: please post only code snippets where you have problems with in the future.
PPS: instance names in my answer do not match your code variables.

Comment: on which object do i call addChild(maskShape)?

Comment: I'm not sure, it's a bit too much code but i think `drawBoard` is the clip where you add some lines on. If this should be the mask you already added it to the stage. You have to specify what clip should work as your mask.

Comment: This is correct you can add all of the drawing objects to a single clip and then set that clip (sprite/movieclip) as the mask object.

Comment: Then, when the shape is filled with a color, make `drawBoard` a mask. `movieClipWhichShouldBeMasked.mask = drawBoard`. I can't see from your code which clip MovieClip should be masked.

Comment: Okay so the mask doesn't need to be a movieclip symbol?

Comment: the mask can be any type of `DisplayObject`. I assume you try to set the mask via Timline in Flash. That won't work in this case. Give your symbol instance on the stage, which should be masked an instance name and on the end of your function `drawLines()` add `drawBoard.cacheAsBitmap =true; nameOfTheInstance.cacheAsBitmap = ture; nameOfTheInstance.mask = drawBoard;`

Comment: Thanks for you help! It's working! I had to add the lines object as the mask, which is the shape! But thanks again!